# Is the usage of the word 'entitled' appropriate in the following extract from a city council meeting?

Tags: word-usage, semantics, legalese

Is the usage of the word 'entitled' appropriate in the following extract from a city council meeting?

An ordinance of the City Commission ... , relating to updating … Chapter 18 ... by:  Amending section 105-57 **entitled**  “Exterior Containers for Storage” .

I have checked Harbrace Handbook, where the exact example, intitled vs entitled, was not specifically mentioned.  I have checked my usual set of dictionaries and the use of **entitled** was generally considered appropriate in the following context by a single dictionary, OED, where it was considered an archaic usage.:  *The child completed high school in the United States and earned straight-As and thus she was *entitled* to be named Valedictorian."

Whereas the other dictionaries seemed to me to recommend the usage that follows:  *He earned straight As and thus was entitled to be named to be named Valedictorian.*. Admittedly, it is a narrow difference, but **intitled** simply sounds better to my ear the contemporary usage.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/entitled) surprisingly lists the 'titled' sense not only without a caveat, but as the first-listed sense. As does Wiktionary. But OALD, Macmillan, CD, and M-W do not even list the sense. (It would be helpful if you list which dictionaries you check next time, to avoid duplication of research.) // I'd say 'titled' is on the way to becoming the usual modern choice. According to Google 3-grams, 'intitled' has always been and remains very rare (qv). Council minutes are doubtless more traditional in format than everyday English.

Comment: [Google 3-grams for _a book titled, a book entitled, a book intitled_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+book+titled%2Ca+book+entitled%2Ca+book+intitled%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

As an *adjective,* "entitled" cannot be used in this way: "an entitled person" does not mean "a person given a name/title." Hence, when defining the word "entitled" on its own, [dictionaries like Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entitled) do not provide this meaning.

However, "entitled" can also be used as a *past participle* of the verb "entitle." [The verb "entitle" can mean](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entitle) "to give a title to a book, film, etc."

In your example, "entitle" is clearly being used in this participial sense. So the meeting minutes are correct; the dictionary definitions for "entitled" as a separate word (i.e. as an adjective) are not relevant.

"Intitled," from the verb "intitle," is, [as Wiktionary notes,](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/intitle#English) archaic or nonstandard.